# Why are there different versions for the last stanza of Lecha Dodi?

Tags: tefilla, shabbat, kabbalat-shabbat

Lecha Dodi was written by Rav Shlomo Halevi Alkabetz ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lekhah_Dodi#Text)). Nusach Ashkenaz and Nusach Sefard have different versions of the last stanza. Why? Where there any doubts as to what Rav Alkabetz wrote, or did someone change something from the original? If so, why?

Comment: What differences are you referring to? ..."שבת מלכתא"? (I have no evidence, but am inclined to believe that שבת מלכתא is a later addition, because it doesn't quite fit the meter of the rest of לכה דודי)

Comment: @Shokhet That and the גם בשמחה vs. גם  ברינה in the two versions. I would also agree that שבת מלכתא was added. I understand the original "source", but if it was added, why? Happy Pesach, and don't kill too much mutton :-) The mezuzah has only so much space!